# With a hosts file Chrome takes too long to realize that 0.0.0.0 isn't real

Tags: windows, google-chrome, hosts-file

So i have a hosts file with many links set to 0.0.0.0, and a lot of times when i go to websites, Chrome is taking too long "waiting for googlesyndication.com" (ad sites that i put in the hosts file) for like 10 seconds. I also noticed this with other browsers such as Firefox and Internet Explorer. Is there a setting somewhere to make chrome to make it timeout faster? Maybe some flags or something i don't know....

Answer (score 3):

I usually use 127.0.0.1, for that reason.  0.0.0.0 actually has semantics that are different from real addresses,  which can lead to unwanted behavior like this.

In other news,  one IPV6 rolls out,  you can use the 100::/64 block for what you're trying to do.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special address that is used for routing. It means if you don't have a concrete route to a target send it over the default route 0.0.0.0.

As Bandrami said, use the loopback address 127.0.0.1 instead which redirects requests to your own PC.